# WPF Desktop Bridge App as chromium native messaging host

Tags: wpf, google-chrome, uwp, chromium, desktop-bridge

I have a client WPF app that uses [`NativeMessagingHost`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging) feature in Chromium browsers.

I've packaged my WPF app into `Windows Store Package (.appx)` via [`Desktop Bridge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root) using `VisualStudio` to publish it in `Windows Store` in the future.

My app works correctly from Store package. Creates `ChromeManifest.json` file. But cannot link manifest to chrome `NativaMessagingHost` name via registry.

Desktop Bridge Apps cannot modify `HKCU\Software\Google\Chrome\NativeMessagingHosts\`. This is allowed but it's modified in sandbox ([proof](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes)), so chrome do not see the registry value.

Result: chrome extension cannot find NativeMessagingHost.

**NOTE:** If I change the registry value to valid value manually via `regedit.exe` - everything works fine!

So, is there any way/workaround to modify registry key or link `ChromeManifest.json` from Desktop Bridge App? Maybe on package install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not allowed from a Store app. You would also need to take care of the Chrome-specific registration when the user installs/registers the app as Chrome extension.

Comment: What exactly isn't allowed in a Store app from what he's describing?